# Now they reverse-engineered Skype, do we have an alternative client?

Tags: skype

The [former question](https://superuser.com/questions/75123/is-there-an-alternative-skype-client) on this subject may be outdated.

[The Skype protocol was reverse engineered and published](http://skype-open-source.blogspot.com/2011/06/skype-protocol-reverse-engineered.html), including [the source](https://github.com/skypeopensource/skypeopensource/downloads).

Has someone written a nice client with this material?

Comment: I am wondering if you can be sued for using the illegal reverse engineered code or any part of it. It has not been long since the release of the information, I am thinking it takes time to develop this type of software, that or no one wants to butt heads with MS lawyers.

Comment: @Moab The USA has probably the death sentence for this, but in the rest of the world it is legal (for now anyway).

Comment: Its patent law, and it worldwide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the answer is, no we haven't, for now.

Answer (score 1):

That code is completely unsupported, however, Skype has had an [API](https://developer.skype.com/) available some time now.

For example, you can use [Pidgin with Skype](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-install-skype-api-plugin-for-pidgin-in-ubuntu.html).

Comment: Which requires running the official client all the time